# Centralized squid server management

Tags: linux, squid

I have 45 Squid Proxy Servers in branch offices and need a way to centrally manage the configuration. How can we can make only one change and have this replication to other Squid servers?

Answer (score 1):

There are several tools that may be able to automate this for you.  [Puppet](http://www.linuxquestions.org/questions/linux-server-73/parameter-to-execute-shell-script-on-puppet-client-through-puppet-server-789202/) & [Chef](https://www.chef.io/chef/) come to mind.